# Get values of Array inside Dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an array as the value of one of my keys in a dictionary and I want to get it to set it as the text of a UITableViewCell. How do I get it? I've been coding in Objective-C and I'm starting to learn Swift.

```
var content: [String: Any] = ["content": ["North America", "Europe West", "Europe Nordic & East", "Oceania", "Russia", "Turkey", "Brazil", "Latin America North", "Latin America South"], "footer": "Select the League of Legends region for this app to use."]

autoreleasepool { () -> () in
    var temp = self.content["content"]
    cell.textLabel?.text = temp[indexPath.row] as String
}
```

This returns me 2 errors `'_??' is not convertible to 'int'` and `'<<error type>>?' is not convertible to 'int'`

Comment: what's your datatype of temp

Comment: Show me the values of dictionary

Comment: @jacky should it inherit the data type of `self.content["content"]`?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon `var content: [String: Any] = ["content": ["North America", "Europe West", "Europe Nordic & East", "Oceania", "Russia", "Turkey", "Brazil", "Latin America North", "Latin America South"], "footer": "Select the League of Legends region for this app to use."]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your dictionary values as AnyObject. You should also use if let to unwrap your optionals:

```
let content: [String:AnyObject] = ["content": ["North America", "Europe West", "Europe Nordic & East", "Oceania", "Russia", "Turkey", "Brazil", "Latin America North", "Latin America South"], "footer": "Select the League of Legends region for this app to use."]

if let temp = content["content"] as? [String] {
     cell.textLabel!.text = temp[indexPath.row]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your temp to Array for getting data.

```
var temp: Array = self.content["content"] as! Array
cell.textLabel?.text = temp[indexPath.row] as! String
```

It will solve your error.

Comment: `'Any?' is not convertible to 'Array<T>'` That might be because I didn't set the array value type when I declared content?

Comment: var content: [String: AnyObject] do this casting

Answer (score 2):

This is because it doesn't know what's kind of type in your temp. Swift is an type safe language.

I write this in playground:

```
var content: [String: AnyObject] = ["content": ["North America", "Europe West", "Europe Nordic & East", "Oceania", "Russia", "Turkey", "Brazil", "Latin America North", "Latin America South"], "footer": "Select the League of Legends region for this app to use."]

var temp:NSArray = content["content"] as! NSArray

let cellString = temp[0] as! String

print(cellString)
```

[image]

Comment: its habit from when I used to aggressively optimize memory usage and clear stuff immediately after I finish using it.